# Data type and sum time duration

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, sum

## What I have:

A MySQL table consisting of a "duration" column.

```
05:00:00
00:30:00
00:30:00
00:15:00
01:45:00
00:30:00
01:30:00
02:30:00
01:00:00
01:30:00
```

## Data Type:

I first used TIME but from what I've researched, TIME is for storing a point in time rather than a duration of time. TIME also represents a limitation in that it can't exceed 23 hours.

I've instead opted for the DATETIME data type. My column now looks as follows:

```
0000-00-00 05:00:00
0000-00-00 00:30:00
0000-00-00 00:30:00
0000-00-00 00:15:00
0000-00-00 01:45:00
0000-00-00 00:30:00
0000-00-00 01:30:00
0000-00-00 02:30:00
0000-00-00 01:00:00
0000-00-00 01:30:00
```

## Sum:

I need the total duration. I.e. SUM of the "duration" column in HH:MM:SS.

Summing the column produces "134000".

```
SELECT sum(`duration`) FROM `my_table`
```

## My question:

How do I sum the duration column in a HH:MM:SS format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`duration`)));
```

> `TIME_TO_SEC` - will convert `datetime` to seconds. Then the `SUM` in your case will be 54000
>
> `SEC_TO_TIME` - convert it back to datetime format
>
> **Output**
>
> 15:00:00

Comment: Using the same query, my output is 13:13:20 whereas yours is 18:43:20. The sum of the column in my question should be 15:00:00.

Comment: My bad! I thought you just wanted to format it. Will re-post my answer. Deleting this one.

Comment: Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Why do you need `TIME_FORMAT` call if, according to MySQL docs, `SEC_TO_TIME` returns data in `00:00:00` format?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for correcting. Corrected my post :).